# Carrierwave is adding black background to image with transparent background when using remote_xxx_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

When I import an image with carrierwave using remote_xxx_url like this one (which has a transparent background)
https://d1fj5empgslmyx.cloudfront.net/uploads/company/470/medium_logo.jpg

It adds a black background color to it
[image]

I think this happens because the original image was a jpg and once imported on amazon it was converted to jpg. Therefore the transparent background color is not really transparent...

I tried forcing the remote_xxx_url to save the image as png again but it does not work. (I don't mind a white background color)

How could I fix that ?

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def store_dir
    "#{ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME']}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_allowlist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png svg webp)
  end

  process resize_to_fit: [500, 500]

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [150, 150]
  end

  def filename
    @name ||= "#{mounted_as}_#{timestamp}.png" if original_filename.present?
  end

  def timestamp
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_timestamp"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, Time.now.to_i)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Remote url's web response can be causing this issue. Try using different remote url, with a white background as you described it and then share the results with us again. If it works on another url, the remote URL's response to carrierwave can be causing this.

And also, the picture you linked has no background. So, try using another viewer to preview your downloaded picture. It may have no background, but maybe browser fills the empty space with black color?

Comment: The issue only happens when it's a .png with no background. The image is converted to having a black background.